# let user : User = new User (....) Why this doesn't work for me ?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Hi i'm trying to create a new user and this syntaxe doesn't work 
it says that 'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```js
 onSubmit() {
    if (this.userForm.valid) {

        let user: User = new User(null,
        this.userForm.controls['cin'].value,
        this.userForm.controls['familyName'].value,
        this.userForm.controls['givenName'].value,
        this.userForm.controls['email'].value,
        this.userForm.controls['description'].value,
        this.userForm.controls['code'].value);
        this.adminService.createUser(user).subscribe();
     }
  }
```

```js
export interface User {
  cin: string;
  givenName: string;
  familyName: string;
  role: string;
  id: string; 
  email: string;   
}
```

is this because User is declared as an interface ? how can i resolve it ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, interfaces do not have constructor, they are just types that inform the compiler about the shapes of objects, so that the compiler can check your code and are erased at compile time. The simplest way would be to us an object literal to create an object that satisfies the interface:

```
export interface User {
    cin: string;
    givenName: string;
    familyName: string;
    role: string;
    id: string; 
    email: string;   
}
let user: User = {
    cin: this.userForm.controls['cin'].value,
    familyName: this.userForm.controls['familyName'].value,
    givenName: this.userForm.controls['givenName'].value,
    email: this.userForm.controls['email'].value,
    id : "", // not sure where this comes from 
    role: ""  // not sure where this comes from 
}
```

You could also create a class that implement the interface, but that is not usually required if you don't have any methods. Also you might want to mark some fields as optional (for example id, you can do this using like this: `id?: string;` )

Comment: Yes ! this is what i was talking about ! i just wanted to make sure that it was because of the 'interface' thing. Thank you =) !

Answer (score 3):

Use `class` instead of `interface` if you use keyword `new`

```
export class User {
  cin: string;
  givenName: string;
  familyName: string;
  role: string;
  id: string; 
  email: string;   
}
```

Comment: it worked  ! Thank you i just wanted to make sure that it was because of it =)

Answer (score 2):

Titian is right. However, you could also do this, if you're declaring and designing at the same time:

```
let user = <User>{
   // properties of User interface
};
```